# Configure procrun in Linux machine?

Tags: java, windows-services, procrun

I am very new to procrun. Please, can anyone suggest how to make a Java application run as a Windows service?  Step by step if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used procrun but as an alternative, I can recommend YAJSW.

Some of my colleagues successfully used it to wrap a jar as a windows service.

The quick start here should help:

http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/#mozTocId527639